# Perl how to send zip file to browser for download in PSGI

Tags: perl, psgi

I am started to look at the PSGI, I know the response from the application should be an array
ref of three elements, [code, headers, body]:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $app = sub {
  my $env = shift;

  return [
    200,
    [ 'Content-type', 'text/plain' ],
    [ 'Hello world' ],
  ]
};
```

The question is how to send a file for example zip or pdf for download to the browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set the correct headers and body.

```
my $app = sub {
  my $env = shift;

  open my $zip_fh, '<', '/path/to/zip/file' or die $!;

  return [
    200,
    [ 'Content-type', 'application/zip' ], # Correct content-type
    $zip_fh, # Body can be a filehandle
  ]
};
```

You might want to experiment with adding other headers (particularly 'Content-Disposition').

Comment: good answer, should I set `binmod $zip_fh;` on the file before returning the response.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [perl dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/); it has psgi support and is a very lightweight framework.

**example:**

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl
 use Dancer;

 get '/' => sub {
     return send_file('/home/someone/foo.zip', system_path => 1);
 };

 dance;
```

**run with**
`chmod 0755 ./path/to/file.pl; ./path/to/file.pl`

**call with:**

`wget <host>:<port>/`

Comment: unfortunately I am not using any frameworks, just need a raw method to send the file through PSGI.

Comment: In that case, try taking a look at this http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Plack-1.0030/lib/Plack/Response.pm; it says that $response->body() can take a file handle.